# Center a play button in a CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to center a play button (for a media app) in the center of a `CircularProgressIndicator`. The code I have technically centers the play button but it doesn't look centered because of the image's shape:

[image]

This is what the same code looks like with the pause button:

[image]

I could add a `layout_marginStart` to the play button but that will screw up the layout and cause adjacent views to move.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_item_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/row_item_progress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/row_item_progress"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/row_item_progress"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/row_item_progress" />

    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/row_item_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:trackThickness="3.5dp"
        app:indicatorSize="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What about creating your own "play" icon, which is shifted a little to the right?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to center the "play" button in the drawable resource (change the image's shape), could you share the play icon?

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably just create a new image. I was hoping there was something in `ConstraintLayout` I could use like an offset but I guess not. Thanks.

Comment: @Kris B: An offset would be `layout_marginStart` or `buttonStart.setTranslationX(20f)`, but you rejected this solution.